# How to vote in Random Forest using Python?

Tags: python, random-forest, voting, ensemble-learning

I try to implement Random Forest using Python, I know there is library sklearn but it's using the probability. What I try to do is using voting to decided the class. The accuracy is so different. The input class is 0 and 1.

Here is my code

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

estimators = []
preditions = []

labelenc_ = LabelEncoder()
labelenc_.fit(Y_train)
classes_ = labelenc_.classes_

for i in range(5):
    t = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1, criterion='entropy', max_features='log2')
    idx = np.random.choice(X_train.index ,size=len(X_train), replace=True)
    fitted_clf= clone(t).fit(X_train.loc[idx,:],labelenc_.transform( Y_train[idx]))
    estimators.append(fitted_clf)

pool = np.asarray([clf.predict(X_test) for clf in estimators]).T
v = tmp= np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.argmax(np.bincount(x))  ,arr=pool,axis=1)
v = labelenc_.inverse_transform(v)
```

I use the predict() method in sklearn get accuracy around 0.7 but when I use my code the accuracy around 0.5, with the same parameter

Comment: Your question is unclear. Sounds like incomplete. What is the specific question?

Comment: I try to use voting in random forest, but the result is different from sklearn @FatihAkici